# Jquery mobile named anchors jumping to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I hope someone can tell me what is going wrong for me I am using JQM to detect a form and parse the named anchor out then move the page down to the link.

```
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script

<script>
$("#target").on('submit', function( ) { 


  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );

   $('.container a[href^=#]').bind('click vclick', function (ev) {
        location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
t
  event.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

The above code works and acts fine as I would expect. however once I link the JQM .js file which I require then load the page it moves the named anchor on the page, then instantly moves back to the top of the screen. So including the below library seems to be the issue, but I cant leave it out is there a work around.

```
 <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know a work around to keep the named anchor on screen once its loaded? and stop it shooting to the top.

Thanks in advance

original source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<title>test</title>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-ajax="false">
  <div data-role="header" id="headerbanner">
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content"> 

<form action="#id1" id="target" class="same-page-link" method="post" data-ajax="false">
<input type='submit' name='button' value='Submit Button' data-theme='a'  />
</form>

<br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br>
<br>Some breaks to lengthen page
<a id="id1" data-ajax="false">Here is</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    </p>
    <p class="maintext">&nbsp;</p>
  </div><!-- /content -->
  <div data-role="footer" id="footerbox">
  </div>
  <!-- /footer -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


<script>
   $('.container a[href^=#]').bind('click vclick', function (ev) {
        location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });

  event.preventDefault();


</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're question isn't clear "_it moves the named anchor on the page, then instantly moves back to the top of the screen_"? moves to a new page? Please add more details and setup a fiddle.

Comment: @omar added the full source thank you.

Comment: Just add `data-ajax="false"` to anchors. And remove click handler function.

Comment: So anchor should be "<a href="#id1" data-ajax="false">Here is</a>"? still same problem

Comment: Yes, this should work.